# Why is calling CompiledCode.Execute from C# for an IronPython script not behaving as expected

Tags: c#, ironpython, dynamic-language-runtime

I am trying to call an IronPython (2.7.1) script from C# (4.0)

This is related to [IronPython integration in C#: a specific problem/question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292366/ironpython-integration-in-c-a-specific-problem-question)

I have a python script like below in a file script.py

```
import clr

def getStream(activity):
    if activity.ActivityType == 'XXX':
        if activity.Complexity == 'LOW':
            return 1
        else:
            return 2
    else:
        return 0

getStream(activity)
```

I am trying to pre-compile the script and reuse it later

```
ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
ScriptSource source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile("script.py");
CompiledCode compiledCode = source.Compile();
dynamic scope = engine.CreateScope();
// .. creating an activity object here
scope.SetVariable("activity", activity);
```

Now to get the streamId if I do this it doesn't work

```
int streamId = rule.Execute<int>(scope);
```

The exception is
*IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.TypeErrorException was unhandled by user code
  Message=expected int, got NoneType*

But this will work

```
rule.Execute(scope);
int streamId = scope.getWorkstream(activity);
```

My question is what is the correct usage of calling Execute method of the CompiledCode class ?

Comment: _`"it doesn't work"`_ - care to explain what happens?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852386/ironpython-dlr-passing-parameters-to-compiled-code

Comment: @sehe rule.Execute<int>(scope); throws an exception like expected int but got null type or something similar. I can later update with the exact exception. If I just do rule.Execute(scope) the object returned is null.

Answer (score 2):

I believe `Execute` will only return a value if the compiled code is an expression, not a series of statements. Your second usage is the correct one in this case.

If the code was simply '2 + 2' then `Execute<int>` would probably work, but I'm unable to check that at the moment.